# How to listen to time change events with the YouTube IFrame Player API?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I couldn't find any way to listen to time changes (so I can show a current time/duration of the video in my UI) on the YouTube IFrame Player API documentation. Is there a way to do this without polling `getCurrentTime()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The YouTube IFrame Player API doesn't expose any way to listen for time change updates, but since internally it uses [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) events to communicate between the IFrame and the main window, you can add a listener to your window to listen to them and react only to the time change ones:

```js
// Instantiate the Player.
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player = new YT.Player("player", {
    height: "390",
    width: "640",
    videoId: "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  });

  // This is the source "window" that will emit the events.
  var iframeWindow = player.getIframe().contentWindow;

  // So we can compare against new updates.
  var lastTimeUpdate = 0;

  // Listen to events triggered by postMessage.
  window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // Check that the event was sent from the YouTube IFrame.
    if (event.source === iframeWindow) {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

      // The "infoDelivery" event is used by YT to transmit any
      // kind of information change in the player,
      // such as the current time or a playback quality change.
      if (
        data.event === "infoDelivery" &&
        data.info &&
        data.info.currentTime
      ) {
        // currentTime is emitted very frequently,
        // but we only care about whole second changes.
        var time = Math.floor(data.info.currentTime);

        if (time !== lastTimeUpdate) {
          lastTimeUpdate = time;
          console.log(time); // update the dom, emit an event, whatever.
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[See it live](https://codepen.io/zavan/pen/PoGQWmG).

Note that this relies on a private API that may change at anytime without previous notice.